# Break after certain memory limit hit

Tags: c++, visual-studio, memory, breakpoints

Is there a way to have visual studio break a c++ project if the exe reaches a certain memory limit? Say if 200mb is used by the exe, then it will break and show me the line of code it is at.

Comment: There should be a setting to change how much memory you give the program to run in.  Set it to 200mb and your breakpoint will be a stackoverflow.

Comment: @James: Memory can come from a variety of sources, not just the stack.

Answer (score 3):

Are you talking about the working set size or heap memory? Heap memory is easy: The debugging VC++ Runtime has _CrtSetAllocHook, which calls a user supplied function on every memory allocation/reallocation/free call.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/820k4tb8.aspx

You could install the hook and then sum the memory allocations. If you hit your threshold value, you can call _debugbreak() to drop into the debugger.